# background image look cold / different from the original image

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

i have ubuntu 19.04 and i have noticed that when i set an image as a background image, it looks different from the original one , the colors are different, and that's for all of my images :

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is ths original image resolution? and your current resolution? this may be the cause.. scaling and shrinking etc..

Comment: what happens when you increase and decresing the screen Brightness? at any stage are you getting same for the original Image and Desktop Background?

Comment: I think you need to install `dconf-editor` `sudo apt install dconf-editor` and search for picture opacity.. which further gives option for desktop background pic opacity..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my background looking washed out. I used a picture from my DSLR I had edited in photoshop and exported as JPG (note: not jpg).
I found the colors were very washed out. I noticed the default wallpapers were saved as jpg.

I solved this issue by opening my file in gimp. When it prompts to change color profile decline. Export file and change the extension to jpg